# Automatically show the texture of selected node (or selected material)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

Is there any way to automatically show the texture of selected node (or selected material) in the UV/image editor? When I use a lot of textures in a project, then a manual search of the appropriate texture is annoying.

Comment: In cycles you can go to the node editor and see whats the texture you are using in your selected object....

Comment: Yes, I know, but when I´m in node editor with specific image texture node, I want to quickly show appropriate image texture of this node in UV/image editor instead of manually selecting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution: select required material, eventually required texture node in node editor, after that switch to "Texture paint" mode, relavant texture will be displayed in UV/image editor automatically

Comment: This does not affect the image shown for UV editing.