# How to auto update the image texture of UV Map window for the selected object?

Tags: uv

Currently, when I click on an object, it's not changing its correspondent current texture shown on the UV Map Window:

[image]

When I click on the second object, Blender is still showing the Texture of the first object...

[image]

I'm in Object mode, in the Layout window, where I just subdivided to show the UV Map window. Currently, if I want to see the correspondent texture of the selected object I have to:

1. Click on the object
2. Press Tab to enter in the Edit mode
3. Press A to select all.
   Only then can I see the corresponding texture.

But I'd like to have the UV texture automatically updated simply by clicking on the object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic update of the image in the UV/image Editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/automatic-update-of-the-image-in-the-uv-image-editor)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98925/78972

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this answers my question. I'm in Object mode, in the Layout window, where I just subdivided to show the UV Map window. Currently, if I want to see the correspondent texture of the selected object I have to: 
1) Click on the object 
2) Press Tab to enter in the Edit mode
3) Press A to select all.
Only then can I see the corresponding texture. 
But I'd like to have the UV texture automatically updated simply by clicking on the object